# Is it possible to attach audio effects to a soundpool in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, soundpool

No matter how many codes I read through I cannot attach presetReverb to a soundpool in Android Studio.

Is it even possible?

```
    presetReverb = new PresetReverb(0, 0);
    presetReverb.setPreset(PresetReverb.PRESET_LARGEHALL);
    presetReverb.setEnabled(true);
```